# MS Access $ in Table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I made a form that adds info.

```
With rst
     .AddNew
     .Fields("a") = b.Value
     .Update
```

It usually works fine. But sometimes I need to put a dollar amount in. So I'll put "$3.43" and it will put the entry in twice. Once at the bottom, and once overwriting the top.
I'm fairly sure this has to do with the "$", because that's the only thing that changes from entry to entry, but I can't find anything about it on Google.

Edit: Full Code

```
Private Sub Command78_Click()
Dim rst As Recordset
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Service Calls")
With rst
     .AddNew
     .Fields("Project Name") = proj.Value
     .Fields("Service Address") = address.Value
     .Fields("Date of Service") = doS.Value
     .Fields("Technician") = tech.Value
     .Fields("Total Billed") = billed.Value
     .Fields("Zip Code") = zip.Value
     .Fields("Description of Work") = work.Value
     .Fields("Type of Call") = toC.Value
     .Fields("Invoice Number") = invoiceNum.Value
     .Fields("Ticket Number") = ticketNum.Value
     .Update
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the data type of the field "a"?

Comment: I don't think that the code in your Question will add and/or modify more than one record in any case. - Have you bound the form to the same table as well? Maybe you are overwriting an exisiting record by data entry in the form through the databinding (Recordsource) and you add another one by executing the VBA code.

Comment: @MattHall It's Short Text

Comment: @PhilS Why would it only happen when I use the "$" symbol?

Comment: add you full code, please

Comment: @SaagarEliasJacky Full code is now posted

Comment: what do you mean by this `Once at the bottom, and once overwriting the top` when you are just adding a record?

Comment: Instead of `.Fields("myTableField") = myFormField.Value` try `!myTableField = Me.myFormField` to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @MattHall I lied, it didn't work. I just hadn't found the messed up row yet.

Comment: @SaagarEliasJacky Say the last entry is id number 84. It will be 84, and 1.

Comment: Was the record with ID 1 was already created? Are you trying to add records to a blank table? Did you try cleaning up the table and try again?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will fix it, but you should always close the recordset and clear it from memory when you're finished with it. Below your `End With` line, put `rst.close` and on the next line `Set rst = Nothing`

Comment: @SaagarEliasJacky It is a table that currently has close to 100 entries. It adds the record to the bottom, as designed. Then it adds a record to the top, overwriting whatever the top record was. I'm unsure of what you mean by "cleaning up the table"

Comment: Another thing to check: is your form's Data Entry property set to Yes?

Answer (score 0):

If Total Billed is of Currency (as it should), you cannot insert a string. Thus, remove a $-sign if present:

```
.Fields("Total Billed").Value = CCur(Replace(billed.Value, "$", ""))
```

Comment: I think Chris has said in the comments it's short text, though I agree it should be in its proper data type

Comment: It's short text because we don't always use currency. We may put the word "Warranty"

Comment: Then you are hosed by bad design. You should add a Boolean field to mark if service is covered by warranty. When marked, set the Billed Value to Null.

Comment: @Gustav That was actually a solution that I came up with, but the PM said that wouldn't work because sometimes he needs to add letters for something or another. It saves him time so he doesn't have to go through pages of description to find why we billed a certain amount.

Comment: Well, go back and tell her that laziness is a poor building ground for solid solutions. "Smart" workarounds will always burn you sooner or later.

Comment: @Chris If not boolean, then you can use a short Type field of 1-5 characters.  You could define it as a 1 character field, and have C be Currency, W be Warranty, etc.  Have a lookup table that defines the possible values so you can add/remove/modify them.  You could use an int field, which is more efficient, but (IMO) less usable.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have bound the table to the same form in which the `Command78_Click` fires, check that and remove the code for the `Command78_click` event if you have actually bound the table to the form.